# ERROR: Unable to parse conf/bitbake.conf: [Errno 2]

Tags: linux, debian, embedded, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to use Yocto/poky with nneta-elbe to build a debian based custom linux image.

I am getting this error:

> ERROR: Unable to parse conf/bitbake.conf: [Errno 2] file conf/bitbake.conf not found in /home/yocto/Projects/yocto/poky/meta-poky:/home/yocto/Projects/yocto/build-elbe2:/home/yocto/Projects/yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp:/home/yocto/Projects/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-python:/home/yocto/Projects/yocto/poky/nneta-elbe:/home/yocto/Projects/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-oe

This is what my bblayer.conf looks like:

```
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"
BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/yocto/Projects/yocto/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/yocto/Projects/yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/yocto/Projects/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /home/yocto/Projects/yocto/poky/nneta-elbe \
  /home/yocto/Projects/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  "
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: As the error says, the file "bitbake.conf" cannot be found. Investigate this further...

Comment: This error only occurs with nneta-elbe. For other builds bitbake.conf is parseable: although for both the method and commands for generating the bitbake build environment is same

Comment: Did you check that the file exists in one of the listed paths? (Read and **understand** the error message, please!)

Answer (score -1):

It is looking for bitbake.conf. Normally, it's located under `meta/conf/bitbake.conf`. You can do a `find /home/yocto/Projects/yocto/poky/ -name bitbake.conf` yourself.

I think, you need to add

```
/home/yocto/Projects/yocto/poky/meta \
```

to your BBLAYERS list.